# Swift remove reference to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, memory, uiview

I want to completely remove a reference to a UIView when it is tapped (it is a subview.

```
@IBAction private func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if (delegate != nil) {
        delegate?.imageWasTapped(imageView.image!, photoURL: photoURL!)
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    print ("tap")
}
```

removeFromSuperview() seems to be insufficient to completely remove the instance (from what I've read), so would like to

```
self = nil
```

but of course self is immutable.

I tried to pass the value to my superview as an inout argument, but of course self is still immutable.

```
        delegate?.imageWasTapped(imageView.image!, photoURL: photoURL!, imageView: self)
```

Is removeFromSumerview() sufficent to deallocate a UIView from memory, or how is this best done?

Comment: When you are using ARC leave it to the system to manage your memory for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can weak reference to that `UIView`. Then the `UIView` will be nil with ARC after you removed it by using `removeFromSuperview`.